# Asus USB N10 wireless adapter works on Ubuntu but not Fedora

Tags: fedora, drivers, wifi

I could make it work in Ubuntu, due to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50684/what-are-these-errors-when-i-try-to-make-the-driver-of-my-wireless-adapter/51303#51303). But the same approach shows no result in Fedora 15 (64 bits).

The device is an Asus USB N10 (wireless-usb converter): Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1786 ASUSTek Computer, Inc.

Any idea how to make it work? Fedora doesn't come with this driver?

Answer (score 1):

Once you download the driver from the [the Realtek site](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8192SE), you should be able to build it and install it like so:

First, make sure you have the dev-tools installed

```
yum groupinstall development-tools
```

and then `cd` into the directory:

```
su -
make
make install
```

and then reboot...

Comment: Before I restart my computer and enter the Fedora to try, please tell me, this "yum" will require internet access?

Comment: If you _haven't_ already installed devel-tools, then you will either need Internet access or you will have to copy the packages across on a flash drive...

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. I got `make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.38.6-26.rc1.fc15.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2`, any idea what's wrong? By the way, you mean the directory of the driver of the cd, or the `/lib/firmware/RTL8192SU`? I tried both with no success..

Comment: Did you install development-tools? It doesn't look like it. If you did, you may need to restart. And, yes, you need to be in the downloaded (and extracted) directory of the firmware when you run make.

Comment: The `make` command do exist, so I thought I had it installed.. Where can I download this development-tools? I can just find the "yum" command over the web..

Comment: Yum is the Fedora package management software. Are you sure you wouldn't be happier with Ubuntu?

Comment: I like the gnome3 =) And I wanna try some different distributions.. I found the development-tools package for "omega 12", not sure if it's the same thing..

Comment: Omega is a Fedora Remix http://omega.dgplug.org/ I am not really able to help you any further at this point. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Download the driver from the RealTek site, as previously noted.

If you cannot build kernel modules on Fedora, you need to install the `kernel-devel` package that *perfectly* matches the kernel you are booting. See this [CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source) page for some details that may help.